# Get selected value from select_from_array field using laravel 5.2 Backpack

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I am  using Laravel 5.2 Backpack in my new project where I have a `select_from_array` field in my form, depending upon the selected value I want data to be displayed in another `select_from_array` field. Don't know how to do that. Please help me with this. This is my code

Controller.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (Request::segment(3) == 'create') {
        $parentField1 = [
        'name' => 'cat_id',
        'label' => 'Category',
        'type' => 'select_from_array',
        'options' => $this->categories(),
        'allows_null' => false,
        ];
        $parentField = [
            'name' => 'subCat_id',
            'label' => 'SubCategory',
            'type' => 'select_from_array',
            'options' => $this->subcategories(),
            'allows_null' => false,
        ];

        array_unshift($this->crud['fields'], $parentField1,$parentField);

    }

public function categories()
{
    $cat = Request::get('cat_id');

    $currentId = 0;
    if (Request::segment(4) == 'edit' and is_numeric(Request::segment(3))) {
        $currentId = Request::segment(3);
    }

    $entries = Category::where('translation_lang', config('app.locale'))->where('parent_id',0)->orderBy('lft')->get();
    if (is_null($entries)) {
        return [];
    }

    $tab = [];
    $tab[0] = 'Root';
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ($entry->id != $currentId) {
            $tab[$entry->translation_of] = '- ' . $entry->name;
        }
    }
    return $tab;
}

public function subcategories()
{
    $currentId = 0;

    if (Request::segment(4) == 'edit' and is_numeric(Request::segment(3))) {
        $currentId = Request::segment(3);
    }

    $entries = Category::where('translation_lang', config('app.locale'))->where('parent_id','!=' ,0)->orderBy('lft')->get();

    if (is_null($entries)) {
        return [];
    }

    $tab = [];
    $tab[0] = 'Root';
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ($entry->id != $currentId) {
            $tab[$entry->translation_of] = '- ' . $entry->name;
        }
    }
    return $tab;
}
```

I want the id of selected option in the `subcategories()` where I can use the id to get the data.

Comment: You are missing the closing `}` on the __construct method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for you is to create a custom field type for this particular purpose, that includes both selects. Follow [this procedure](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-custom-field-types). Start from the `select2.blade.php` file and add the javascript you need to achieve your goal (on change event on first select2, change the options in the next select2).

Comment: actually, in my databse both the category and subcategory are saved in the same table, and i don't know how to write relations. when i use select2 they ask for relation function..... please help me with this

Comment: I understand. The select2 field won't work without relationships. Honestly, relationships are a must do in Laravel. Otherwise you probably shouldn't use Laravel at all. You can learn about relationships in the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships - but personally I'd recommend spending $9 for a month-access at Laracasts. You can learn Laravel really really easily by watching a few videos. This one in particular explains a lot of core concepts, as well as relationships (video 8): https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch